# JavaFX, problemas al crear .jar

Tags: javafx

es la primera vez que creo una applicación con javaFX, llevo más de 3 dias tratando de poder generar un .jar que funcione para poder distribuirlo. He estado tratando de solucionarlo con Chatgpt y otras herramientas de inteligencia artificial, pero me topo con el mismo problema.

Estoy usando el `jdk 17.0.9` y el `sdk 17.0.9`.

Se trata de una aplicación para gestionar una base de datos SQLite, con la función de crear un pdf con cierta información de esta base de datos. Cuando corro la aplicación en el IDE, en este caso Intellij, se ejecuta a la perfección y no genera ningún error y funciona toda la lógica programada.

El problema surge a la hora de ejecutar el .jar que creo mediante el `Artifacts` o mediante el `maven`, he probado todos los plugins que me ha dicho Chatgpt y nada cuando ejecuto el .jar me da el error `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`.

Lo he probado practicamente todo hasta ejecutando el .jar con el comando `java --module-path "ruta\javafx-sdk-17.0.9\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar .\acitunator.jar`

La unica manera en la que he conseguido iniciar el programa y que funcione ha sido con `mvn javafx:run`

Tanto con `Artifacts` como con `mvn package` me sale el error de `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

Tambien vi por youtube que creando una clase y llamando a la clase principal ejecutaria, en concreto una clase con este codigo:

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp.main(args);
    }
}
```

Y si funciona, pero cuando trato de agregar un registro a la base de datos ya deja de funcionar, solo funciona lo relacionado con la interfaz grafica.

He probado a añadir la librerias del SDK directamente a al proyecto, he configurado todas las variables, `JAVA_HOME` `PATH_TO_FX`... He seguido todos los tutoriales y nada, sigo con el mismo problema.

Les dejo también mi archivo `pom.xml` que ha ido cambiando constantemente esperando que Chatgpt lo arreglara milagrosamente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.didelfo</groupId>
    <artifactId>acitunator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>acitunator</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.didelfo.acitunator/com.didelfo.acitunator.MainApp</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Las librerías externas que he utilizado son `itextpdf-5.5.13.3` y `sqlite-jdbc-3.42.0.0`.

También pongo el `module-info.java` ya que en algunos tutoriales he visto que modifican este documento y solucionan el error. Pero hasta ahora a mi no me ha funcionado nada.

```
module com.didelfo.acitunator {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.sql;
    requires itextpdf;


    opens com.didelfo.acitunator to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.didelfo.acitunator;
    opens com.didelfo.acitunator.Controllers to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.didelfo.acitunator.Controllers;
}
```

Espero atentamente una respuesta milagrosa para poder terminar con este sufrimiento y poder dar por finalizada esta aplicación. Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías decirnos en que IDE estás desarrollando tu aplicación? ¿Podrías decirnos qué comando u opción estás ejecutando para generar el archivo final? ¿Podrías decirnos cómo se llama el archivo que estás intentando ejecutar y en qué carpeta se está generando dicho archivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas utilizando el IDE de IntelliJ, esta pequeña guía te puede servir.

#### 1. Crear un fake main

Tienes que crear una nueva clase falsa principal que instancie a tu clase principal, por ejemplo esto:

```
package pe.test.fxapp;

public class FakeMain {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FXApp.main(args);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Configurar artefactos

Te diriges a la ubicación

1. File (Archivo)
2. Project Structure (Estructura de proyecto)

En la nueva ventana en el lado izquierdo, seleccionas Artifacts (artefactos)
[image: Venta de estructura de proyecto]

Luego haces click en el símbolo **+** -> JAR -> From modules with dependecies...
Al abrirse la ventana en donde dice Main Class (Clase principal) buscas la clase falsa que hemos creado y lo seleccionamos y en la sección JAR files from libraries seleccionamos la opción extract to the target JAR.

ahora veremos que un nuevo artifact se ha creado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Tendremos que hacer click en este botón para agregar las librerías externas, seleccionamos library files y en la nueva ventana hacemos una selección múltiple de todas las librerías que tenemos que añadir a nuestro artifact y le damos OK
2. Es la ubicación donde se generará nuestro JAR

Finalmente en la ventana del artifact le damos en apply(aplicar) y luego en OK

#### 3. Generación de ejecutable JAR

Ahora para construir nuestro jar nos vamos a la pestaña de BUILD -> build artifacts y seleccionamos el artifact creado y le damos en la nueva ventana en build. Si todo sale correctamente veremos el siguiente mensaje.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y listo...

Para ejecutar tu JAR simplemente buscas la ubicación de salida y ejecutas el jar.
si en caso tienes un error y no ejecuta la aplicación intenta hacerlo mediante linea de comandos

```
java -jar nombre-de-tu-jar.jar
```

para ver si hay algún error o excepción.

Video Referencia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8ahBtXkQzU